# Copy Rotation constraint without affecting Curve modifier

Tags: modifiers, constraints

I have a Circle Curve with a Copy Rotation constraint with the Camera. I have Texts with Curve Modifier with the Circle Curve.  When I move the camera, the Circle Curve follows the cam, but it breaks the Curve modifier for the text. How do I fix this?

[image: reference image]

I tried to use an Empty where the Circle Curve is parented, and the Empty is then tied with the camera with a Copy Rotation constraint, but the result is the same. What am I doing wrong or what can I do to achieve my goal of having the Text follow the Camera?

[image: reference image]

The test file:
[image]

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I'm looking for a potential solution that doesn't require applying the modifier. My current solution was just to apply the modifier, I'm wondering if there's a solution without applying the modifier.

Comment: so, if I understand correctly, you could parent the text to your empty as well?

Comment: oh fudge, it's that easy and I didn't realise that, so embarrassing 

Comment: i hope i don't get banned for asking stupid questions 

Comment: Don't worry we are all stupid with Blender  ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parent the text to the empty as well